# unsupervised learning - clustering numpy arrays within numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

We're working with a dataset of spoken numbers. The wavefiles are converted to MFCC values. Each row (wavfile) consists of around 20 to 40 (depending on the length of the soundfile) arrays, with 13 floatvalues in each array. The goal of the task is to identify 10 spoken numbers. Because we don't have labels we want to cluster them in 10 groups using a learning method.

The code looks like this:

```
def kmeans(data, k=3, normalize=False, limit= 500):
    """Basic k-means clustering algorithm.
    """
    # optionally normalize the data. k-means will perform poorly or strangely if the dimensions
    # don't have the same ranges.
    if normalize:
        stats = (data.mean(axis=0), data.std(axis=0))
        data = (data - stats[0]) / stats[1]

    # pick the first k points to be the centers. this also ensures that each group has at least
    # one point.
    centers = data[:k]

    for i in range(limit):
        # core of clustering algorithm...
        # first, use broadcasting to calculate the distance from each point to each center, then
        # classify based on the minimum distance.
        classifications = np.argmin(((data[:, :, None] - centers.T[None, :, :])**2).sum(axis=1), axis=1)
        # next, calculate the new centers for each cluster.
        new_centers = np.array([data[classifications == j, :].mean(axis=0) for j in range(k)])

        # if the centers aren't moving anymore it is time to stop.
        if (new_centers == centers).all():
            break
        else:
            centers = new_centers
    else:
        # this will not execute if the for loop exits on a break.
        raise RuntimeError(f"Clustering algorithm did not complete within {limit} iterations")

    # if data was normalized, the cluster group centers are no longer scaled the same way the original
    # data is scaled.
    if normalize:
        centers = centers * stats[1] + stats[0]

    print(f"Clustering completed after {i} iterations")

    return classifications, centers


classifications, centers = kmeans(speechdata, k=5)
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
plt.scatter(x=speechdata[:, 0], y=speechdata[:, 1], s=100, c=classifications)
plt.scatter(x=centers[:, 0], y=centers[:, 1], s=500, c='k', marker='^')
```

the line "classifications, centers = kmeans(speechdata, k=5)" gives me an error: IndexError: too many indices for array.

How do I transform my array of array data, with varying length (one row has shape (20,13) and one might have (38,13) so that I can cluster them?

Comment: on which line inside the function you get error?

Comment: Thanks for your respons! the line "classifications, centers = kmeans(speechdata, k=5)" gives me an error: IndexError: too many indices for array.(thus line 70) 

and         classifications = np.argmin(((data[:, :, None] - centers.T[None, :, :])**2).sum(axis=1), axis=1) --[so line 43]

Comment: check the shape of data and centers before that line.